# Creating dynamic Django Template Variables inside Javascript script tag

Tags: django, django-templates

This is good enough for a fixed variable we already know.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
   var a = "{{someDjangoVariable}}";
</script>
```

I have one scenario, where I wanted to create the variable dynamically. 
e.g -

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
for (i = 1, bar = bar , textb = ""; i <= bar ; i++) 
   {
    for (j = 1, category = category , textc = ""; j <= category ; j++)
     {
      var a = "{{someDjangoVariable + i + j}}";
      // Do some more stuff here in UI - create input field dynamically
     }
   }
</script>
```

In my query dict lets say i have this structure (2 * 2 matrix structure) - `{'someDjangoVariable11' : 1, 'someDjangoVariable12' : 23, 'someDjangoVariable21': 256, 'someDjangoVariable22': 31}`

Please suggest if there is a way to create variables dynamically.

P.S - The columns and rows of matrix may vary as per **User Input**. It can be `2 *3`, `4 * 3`, `1 * 5` etc.

Comment: This question seems to betray a fundamental misunderstanding of how templates and JS works, and the difference between server-side and frontend code.

Comment: @DanielRoseman : I have edited the question, let me know if still not understandable. Thanks!!

Comment: I understood the question; the misunderstanding I was talking about was yours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This approach will not work since the client side variables can not reach back to the server. What I'd suggest is sending back a dictionary of variables from the server.

Server Side:

```
data = {'foo': '1', 'bar': '2'}
return render('template.html', data)
```

Client Side:

```
<script> var data = {{data|json|safe}}; </script>
```

Then you can access it in javascript with the original dictionaries keys.

Comment: Alternatively, you can convert the data to a string with json.dumps() on the server side, and then send that data as a string which removes the need for the "json" filter in the template.

Comment: Can you please answer this. I was not very clear on this post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39067756/creating-dynamic-django-template-variables-names-inside-javascript-script-tag